# First and Last Name Fields Not Showing - Billing Information

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout, billing

One of my client's requirements is that all purchases are made as 'guests' in order to simplify the checkout process.

So what I did was go to 
System > Configuration > Advanced 
and `disabled` the `Mage_Customer`

Everything looked like it was exactly what I needed until I tried the checkout process again. For some reason, the ***First Name*** and ***Last Name*** fields are no longer showing up and I cannot get past the Billing Information step.

[image]

How can I get these fields to show up again while still only allowing for guest purchases? Is it wrong to disable Mage_Customer?

Thanks!
Mike

p.s. I am on Magento ver. 1.9.2.2

Comment: What made you think that disabling  `Mage_Customer` from the admin will let your customer checkout as guests?

Comment: @musicliftsme experimentation ... as it removes all links for customer account log ins, I figured it would be what I was looking for. Do you have any insight on how I may be able to allow only Guest checkout?

Comment: You want to remove first name & last name or what ?

Comment: @Kothari I want the First and Last name fields to show up again. They are currently hidden because I disabled Mage_Customer

Comment: you want to disable right

Comment: @kothari yes I want to disable customer accounts and allow only guests

Comment: So you want to show the guest customer detail step as default step on checkout page instead of the options to register or login?

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

**Note : Don't Edit Core File**

It will remove mandatory fields of First Name & Last Name.

```
UPDATE eav_attribute SET is_required = 0 WHERE attribute_code = 'lastname'
```

**/app/code/local/Mage/customer/Model/Address/Abstract.php:**

```
 /* if (!Zend_Validate::is($this->getLastname(), 'NotEmpty')) {
         $this->addError(Mage::helper('customer')->__('Please enter the last name.'));
     }
*/
```

**/app/code/local/Mage/customer/Model/Customer.php**

```
/*        if (!Zend_Validate::is( trim($this->getLastname()) , 'NotEmpty')) {
        $errors[] = Mage::helper('customer')->__('The last name cannot be empty.');
    }
*/
```

**/app/code/local/Mage/customer/etc/config.xml**

```
<lastname>
                    <billing>1</billing>
                    <shipping>1</shipping>
                    **<required>0</required>** // change from 1 to 0
                    <mapped>1</mapped>
     </lastname>
```

Comment: Okay I will give this a shot... but ideally I would still like to record the buyers First and Last name. Making it optional does not really solve my problem.

Comment: It's working Example it will make it as optional as First name & Last Name

Answer (score 1):

An easier and more cleaner approach is to copy “opcheckout.js” from base theme to your custom theme

```
/skin/frontend/base/default/js/opcheckout.js
```

and place this code after line (45 approx)

```
this.accordion.disallowAccessToNextSections = true;


 this.method = 'guest';
   Element.hide('register-customer-password');
   this.gotoSection('billing', true);
```

and you are done